# How to reset asking for permission for chrome desktop notification

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

`window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission()` *originally* showed the prompt to the user asking them to `Allow` or `Deny`. At one point, when my notification showed up, I clicked on the little wrench and then `Disable from http://example.com` option.

Then, `window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission()` no longer prompted me. Did I permanently stop my site from receiving or even allowing to request for permission? I even went into Chrome settings and opted in for "allow notifications from all sites."

How can I get that prompt to show up again? Currently, `.checkPermission()` is `1`, and I want to make it `0` again.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You disabled notifications for that website locally-only. So only you will have this "problem", and the other users will be fine.

About the Chrome setting to "Allow notifications from all sites", this will only allow websites to request for permissions, but in your case... you already disabled the notifications specifically for that domain.

To re-enable it, follow the example in the image below to find the way to the permission settings per domain. In there, you can see "Notifications". Just update your settings, and you are good to go ;)

More info at: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95617

[image: Permissions]